# how to import file with special character in name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, es6-modules, react-syntax-highlighter

How can I import a file with special characters in it's name in ES6?

I can

`import { tomorrow} from 'react-syntax-highlighter/dist/esm/styles/hljs';`

but I can't:

`import { tomorrow-night} from 'react-syntax-highlighter/dist/esm/styles/hljs';`

Comment: That's the name of the exported function/class/whatever that you are importing, not the file. How are you exporting the identifier?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript do not support hyphens in variable name. They are reserved for subtractions.